# Run VSCode with arguments in MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, hackintosh

VScode has an perfomance issue on my MacOS (actually hackintosh) where the FPS of Scrolling and Typing is so low (around 20fps I guess) and it's bothering me but with this arguments, it lessen the problem on performance

```
code --force-device-scale-factor=2 --disable-gpu
```

But it only applies when launching the VSCode using the terminal. Now I want to apply those options when just launching the VSCode by opening/click the Application.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering question directly but...

Are you sure that you need to pass this flag for `VSCode` running properly? I was using two Hackintoshes in the past and now I'm using M1-based Mac - if you use computer with AMD you should go into `AMD-OSX` wiki and use correct patches. If you use macOS on old laptop like Thinkpad X220/X230 the electron apps like `VSCode` or `discord` can run bit slowly.

Please also test if you got graphical acceleration and if you're using OpenCore, it can fix problems that Clover or ready macOS EFI files can give you.

Comment: I use the monterey on a not fully supported GPU, So I guess this is my fault (graphic acceleration works tho)

Comment: Probably... I suppose you use something like beetwen Intel hd3000 to hd4600 - these GPU's are not very performant, I tried to run Discord on Hackintosh with this GPU and it's little laggy. You could buy higher clocks RAM's and put them in dual channel if your laptop support it and does not have two memory sticks, iGPUs usually benefits from highly-clocked dual RAM, but it won't give you very noticeable improvment.